# Open URL in existing tab in C++ and C

Tags: c++, c, url

I'm trying to open a URL on my Raspberry PI using C++ or C. Using the command `system("xdg-open http://something.com);` the default browser opens the first time, but on every next try a new tab opens. I would like to check, if the browser is open, then open the desired url in the existing tab. There is nothing more to it: no posting of any forms, or reading data from the site. How could I achieve this in C++ and C?

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

Comment: If someone votes down my question, could he or she at least share the answer/link?!?

Comment: Go look at the command line parameters available for your favorite browser -- I've yet to see a browser that offers this level of control. What makes you think that this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `system()` you should configure your default browser, so that it opens all external URLs in the current active tab. For instance with Firefox type in the addres bar `about:config` and search for files begining with `browser.link.open_`. To answer the question, you should configure the files accordingly:
`browser.link.open_external         value = 1 
browser.link.open_newwindow         value = 1 
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external         value = 1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restiction         value = 0`

The above will make sure, that all URLs get open in the same tab, no matter how many times your code repeats itself.
Make sure to open Firefox in advance, otherwise the code will stop running as soon as Firefox opens.